# var usage in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am learning mongoDB by following the tutorial, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

However, the sample code, `var c = db.testData.find()`, confuses me. Without var, the execution just prints out the documents, with the var, c becomes the cursor. The other command, `j = { name : "mongo" }`, I don't see the difference with or without var. I want to be clear when I should have var and when I can ignore var.

I google the question little bit, for example, [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript), it talks about scope. I cannot understand how my question relates to scope.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/

According to this doc,

> However, in the mongo shell, if the returned cursor is not assigned to a variable using the var keyword, then the cursor is automatically iterated up to 20 times to print up to the first 20 documents in the results.

Comment: It's still not clear for me. I can assign variable with or without var in other command, for example, `var j = { name : "mongo" }` vs `j = { name : "mongo" }`. I don't see the difference in execution.

Comment: Ok, forget about what I put there before, here's what mongodb says: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/, search for 'var keyword'

Comment: Yup, according the the documentation, it's designed to work in this way. Thank you for sharing the link.

Answer (score 1):

From the mongo getting started tutorial:

> This tutorial provides an introduction to basic database operations
>   using the mongo shell. mongo is a part of the standard MongoDB
>   distribution and provides a full JavaScript environment with a
>   complete access to the JavaScript language and all standard functions
>   as well as a full database interface for MongoDB. See the mongo
>   JavaScript API documentation and the mongo shell JavaScript Method
>   Reference.

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/

In Javascript it's best practice to not use global variables. You define global variables without the `var` prefix and local variables *with* the `var` prefix. I guess the Javascript implementation in Mongo disabled global variables completely because it's bad practice.

Comment: I found the discussion on this topic in the link I mentioned, but I could not figure it out how my question relates to local or global variable.